# Select voltage source between two voltages (5 V, 0 V) or vice versa, diodes don't work

Tags: voltage, transistors, diodes

I am repairing radios on the bench, and some radios have 5 V on pin 1, and some radios have 5 V on pin 10, but the connector is the same.

I'm bored of always moving 5 V to pin 1, 10, 1, 10, ... I want to make something more universal.

Let's imagine:

- I connect first radio: pin 1 - 5 V, pin 10 - 0 V
- I connect second radio: pin 1 - 0 V, pin 10 - 5 V

1. If I simply connect two wires together (1 and 10), everything will work, but I can burn pin X on the motherboard, because pin 1 and pin 10 will both have 5V, and that's not OK; only one pin can have 5V.
2. I can put a switch between pin 1 and pin 10, and switch between them, but one day I will simply forget to.
3. I want to make this automatic; something (component X) sets the voltage for USB socket from pin 1 or pin 10. This is how I tried to do this with diodes, but I still have 5 V on both pins 1 and 10, why?

[image]

[image]

And this is how I want it to work, do I need transistors here?

[image]

This is how it should be:

[image]

To sum things up: I want to have two wires connected to the connector, but 5 V should be on only one of them; if the radio provides 5 V on pin 1, then pin 10 should be 0 V, and vice versa.

Comment: Is the 5 V source **coming from** inside the radio or are you feeding 5 V **into** the radio. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Transistor 5V coming from inside the radio, and it must go to usb socket

Comment: A simple solution is to have two cables (clearly labelled) - one wired to match Radio A, the other to match Radio B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a full-bridge rectifier with a suitably low voltage drop.

The lowest-cost solution would be a half-bridge rectifier built out of Schottky diodes to minimize the voltage drop, and an "on-off" switch that turns the load ON based on the polarity of the source. This switch does the job of a mechanical rectifier. Setting the switch to the "OFF" position won't damage anything - it just turns the load off. The ON and OFF positions depend on the polarity of the source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3uka.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D5 is the "power on" indicator.

The voltage across the load vs. the load current is plotted below. The voltage drop across the rectifier is below 0.35A for load currents up to 1.5V.

[image: Load voltage vs load current]

Another approach, in the same spirit, uses two NMOS FETs as an ideal rectifier, with negligible voltage drop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4094b.png)</sup>

The output voltage should be above 4.9V for the full load range (0-1.5A).

With four fets, the switch can be removed, and the circuit self-switches:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foscaZ.png)</sup>

The output voltage remains above 4.9V from 0A to 1.5A load current.

**The output voltage calculations assume 5.0V input**. That may not always be the case.

Comment: OK, after re-reading the OP's comments, I see that the external USB device will be the load, so the negative current reflects that. However, I wonder if an active current sink is appropriate for what may be a passive USB device.

Comment: @PStechPaul The 5V source is what’s on pins 10 and 1. It can be flipped upside down to check the rectifying function. The current source represents the load. It’s used to calculate the voltage drop on the diodes. It’s a circuit analysis tool, that’s all. It is controlled in a DC sweep from 0 to 1.5A.  Of course a USB device will be more of a variable resistor, but that doesn’t matter. I could have put a resistor there just as well. All those circuits work on breadboard, and perform close to what the simulation predicts.

Comment: I do my best to keep the signal flow left to right, so the load is on the right side, and the supply (pins 1 and 10) are on the left.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDt6bF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How it works:

- If pin 1 is +5 V then RLY1 will be energised and it will be connected to +5 V out while pin 10 will be connected to 0 V out.
- If pin 10 is +5 V then RLY2 will be energised and it will be connected to +5 V out while pin 1 will be connected to 0 V out.

You can't get away with a single DPDT relay in this instance as damage may occur in the brief instant between making the connection and the relay being energised.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but what is a RLY? Is a relay? Can you help me to choose a right one? USB will have 5V and max 2A

Comment: RLY is a relay. The coil has to be 5 V DC. The contacts just have to be rated for 2 A minimum and there have to be two NO (normally open) or DT (double-throw) (but you won't be using the NCs).

Comment: This will only work if the pin that is not +5V is GND/zero volts.  I think more information on the pinouts of the two radios is required to produce a working solution.

Comment: Note that this will *only* work if the pin that isn't 5V is ground, not a signal line or unconnected. That pin *has* to be capable of sinking current.